# DllMain entry point DLL_PROCESS_DETACH

Tags: c#, c++, dllmain

I have a c++ dll, called from a c# process...

```
[DllImport(@"My.dll", EntryPoint = "Function1", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool MyFunction(int id1, int id2, [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder Name);
```

Here is dll entry point...

```
switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        std::cout << "Attach" << std::endl;
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        std::cout << "Detach" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
```

I get one attach and four detach like so...

Attach 
Detach 
Detach 
Detach 
Detach

Can anyone explain why?

The process makes just one call to the function.

Comment: Why did my problem get a -1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    std::cout << "Detach" << std::endl;
    break;
```

Your code will write "Detach" in console when `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH`, `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` or `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` is fired. If you want only `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` add `break` statements in your `switch`:

```
switch (ul_reason_for_call)
{
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    std::cout << "Attach" << std::endl;
    break;
case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    break;
case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    break;
case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    std::cout << "Detach" << std::endl;
    break;
}
```

or simply omit unused cases.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Solved.